# keep getting error "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')."

Tags: python, dtreeviz

Trying to create tree for this data, not sure what is wrong exactly, but keep getting same error.

```
   import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(sns.load_dataset('titanic').drop(columns=['alive']), random_state=0)
target = 'survived'

!pip install dtreeviz
!apt install graphviz
!apt install xdg-utils

 sex = {'male': 0, 'female': 1,}
train.sex = train.sex.map(sex)
test.sex = test.sex.map(sex)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)

features = ['sex', 'age']
target = 'survived'

model.fit(train[features], train[target])
model.fit(test[features], test[target])

from dtreeviz.trees import *
dtreeviz(model,
         train[features],
         train[target],
         taget_name=target,
         feature_names=features,
         class_names=['deceased', 'survived'])
```

new to python, any help appreciated!

Comment: Please try to make your code a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you using pandas DataFrames? If so, try `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0).` as a starting point.

Comment: also, `df.describe` might be helpful to see the summary of your Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Sorry! just added the rest of the code

Comment: basically, you need to do what the error is saying - eliminate all the NaNs (I bet that's them, not some infinity values or some very large numbers). To do that, you can use `dropna`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html or `fillna`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html